# Get all the orders created by admin username(s)

Tags: magento-enterprise, admin, create-order

I want to get and filter orders based on who created it in admin (Orders grid or Reports).

We have few admin users who creates orders from backend, I want to know whether we can get all the orders created in admin (with admin username) for existing orders or it requires custom functionality? If we can do it, can someone shed light on how to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento Enterprise we can see which admin user did what activity under `System > Admin Actions Log > Report` grid. I created custom module out of it for this requirement. Basically I just filtered it to:

```
Action Group: Sales Orders
Action: Save
Full Action Name: adminhtml_sales_order_create_save
```

and displayed my own report which aggregates the data.

Answer (score 1):

This will require custom functionality, to my knowledge magento do not store this info.

To accomplish this you could

1. Add a field to sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid
2. Create an observer sales_order_place_before
3. In your check if admin and get the admin user id.

Comment: Agree with this. So there is no way to get existing admin usernames associated with orders?